# Unable to use SQL in Crystal Reports to get proper outcome

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, crystal-reports-2008

I have a straightforward query that work just fine in SQL but can't get the data selection to work properly in Crystal Reports.

My SQL statement looks like this.

```
SELECT
    t2.Customer
FROM 
    table2 t2   
INNER JOIN 
    table1 t1 ON t1.order = t2.order 
WHERE 
    t2.status = '         NXT'
```

I created a formula field in Crystal Reports called "customer" but my `SELECT` statement doesn't work. Here is my `SELECT` statement in Crystal.

```
SELECT
     t1.'customer'
FROM
     'table1' t1,
     'table2' t2
WHERE
     t1.'order' = t2.'order',
     t2.'status' = "         NXT"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you got an strange use of quotes and double quotes on the query

Answer (score 3):

You need to use AND in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT
t1.customer
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE
 t1.[order] = t2.[order] AND 
 t2.status = "         NXT"
```

Comment: I tried the above  but I still get an error in Crystal Reports. It is expecting a number, boolean, date ... string after my SELECT.

Comment: @Kevin_H ok. I think this is because order is a keyword. It should be surrounded with square brackets, i.e. `[order]`

Comment: The above syntax doesn't work either but thanks for your help.